# Ascribe a variable to JSON Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How to ascribe a variable to JSON `name`?

**JSON `names` object**

```
[
    { "name": "John", "age" : "12" },
    { "name": "Ben", "age" : "15" },
    { "name": "Jason", "age" : "18" },
    { "name": "Billy", "age" : "11" }
]
```

**Angular service and controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get("jsonfile.json").then(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        this.getNames = function(){
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    });
    app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope, service){
        var promise = service.getNames();
        promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.names = data.data;
            console.log($scope.names);

        });
});
```

What I tried to do in controller:

```
var name = names.name;
```

And then I tried in HTML `ng-repeat {{name}}` but it didn't work.

Comment: $scope.names = data; console.log($scope.names.name)

Comment: just like you did in `secondCtrl` : promise.then(...) was the good way. But anywhere outside the callback passed to `then()` would be useless because service didn't finish retrieving the data

Answer (score 3):

You can just loop over your names object in HTML with [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

If your array is:

```
$scope.names = [
    { "name": "John", "age" : "12" },
    { "name": "Ben", "age" : "15" },
    { "name": "Jason", "age" : "18" },
    { "name": "Billy", "age" : "11" }
];
```

You can show `names.name` with this code:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in names">{{n.name}}</div>
```

Comment: Yes i know i can show names.name with ng-repeat="n in names"

Comment: Well you said in your original post "And then I tried in HTML ng-repeat {{name}} but it didn't work.". What was that supposed to mean ?